# FTP Daemon for Windows?

Tags: windows, ftp

I need to replace an IIS FTP server that uses AD accounts for consultants to transfer files to an organization.  I would like to slowly migrate away from these AD accounts for security reasons.

Whats a good FTPd for Windows that supports:

1. Existing AD credentials (Including user@domain, domain\user forms)
2. As functional as IIS's ftpd (thats not saying much)
3. SCP/SFTP/FTP/HTTPS for FIle Transafers.
4. Perhaps a simple web interface (not critical).

Comment: In regard to point 3, it's either an FTP server or it isn't. You've listed protocols, most notably HTTPS, which are unrelated to FTP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what 'security reasons' you're referencing that wouldn't be present in another Windows solution (that presumably would still rely on Windows security).  However, [FreeNAS](http://freenas.org/doku.php) allows for just about every file transfer method imaginable and has an easy-to-configure active directory authentication connector.  We've had very good luck integrating FreeNAS boxes into our AD domain and it's easy to get up and running in only a few minutes with the web management interface.

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for a FTP server software and stumbled over CrushFTP 5 (http://www.crushftp.com/5.html) today. I havn´t tested it yet but it seams like it will fullfill you needs.

If someone have any experience of CrushFTP then I am listening...